# How do I get reliable UPnP MediaRenderer discover with Kodi 16.1 on Xubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, xbmc, kodi, upnp

I have a HTPC with a fully patched installation of Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Installing Kodi from the Ubuntu repo installs Kodi version 15.2; with this version I can reliably discover the Kodi MediaRenderer and stream music, but I can't play DVDs (see http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=249128). I enabled the XBMC PPA (https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), which allows me to install Kodi 16.1; in 16.1, DVD playback is fine, but the UPnP discovery is now extremely unreliable, with the discovery usually yielding no results. Nothing else has changed on the system.

I can reliably get UPnP control points to detect the presence of a MediaRenderer by disabling and the re-enabling the "Allow remote control via UPnP" option in Kodi, but this is a terrible nuisance. `netstat` indicates Kodi is indeed listening on the UDP port 1900 used for UPnP SSDP, and `tcpdump` shows that the discovery packets are indeed reaching the HTPC, but no responses are sent out. Disabling the firewall service `ufw` does not fix the issue.

What might cause this behavior? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you temporarily disable the firewall using gufw?

Comment: @heynnema good thought! Unfortunately, disabling ufw doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but I am able to reliably discover the Kodi UPNP MediaRenderer if I [build from source](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Compile_Kodi_for_Linux) using the [16.1 tag](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/tree/16.1-Jarvis).